# Convert local image to base64 string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, base64, local

I'm trying to convert a **local** image to Base64 **string**. I am not using any HTML and simply need javascript which references the image's path within the code.

For instance, converting:

```
C:\Users\Work\Desktop\TestImage.jpg
```

into

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QBKRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAADABoBBQABAAAAMgAAABsBBQABAAAAOgAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAVOoqgJaYAABU6iqAlpgA/+IMWElDQ19QUk9GSUxFAAEBAAAMSExpbm8CEAAAbW50clJHQiBYWVogB84AAgAJAAYAMQAAYWNzcE1TRlQAAAAASUVDIH.....etc...
```

There are many posts like this but they all seem to utilize HTML in some way, in order to identify the file path. I'm hoping I can write a defined filepath **within** the javascript.

I tried this to no avail:

```
function convertImgToBase64()
{
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    img = document.createElement('img'),
    img.src = C:\Users\Work\Desktop\TestImage.jpg;
    img.onload = function()
    {
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        alert(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
}
```

One example has the following html and javascript, but I'm hoping this can be consolidated together. Thanks for your support

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>


<input type='file' id="asd" />
<br>
<img id="img" src="//placehold.it/1x1/" />
<div id="base"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);} // Get elem by ID

function readImage() {
    if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
             el("img").src = e.target.result;
             el("base").innerHTML = e.target.result;
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    }
}

el("asd").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);\
```

[Its demo found here](http://jsbin.com/ayazin/453/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try utilizing `XMLHttpRequest()` set `responseType` to `Blob` , use `FileReader()` at `XMLHttpRequest` `onload` event to read response as `data URI`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();       
    xhr.open("GET", "/path/to/local/image/file", true); 
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
            console.log(this.response);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
               var res = event.target.result;
               console.log(res)
            }
            var file = this.response;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    };
    xhr.send()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for files referenced without being hosted on a sever, it will not work for the path mentioned above "C:\Users\Work\Desktop\TestImage.jpg" as Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes such as http

Comment: @WessamElMahdy See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996001/jquery-load-only-working-in-firefox/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279589/read-local-xml-with-js/