# Can the mechanism that loads the worker in Shared Web Workers be modified?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

Please see this related question for a background to this:

[How can I load a shared web worker with a user-script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810002/how-can-i-load-a-shared-web-worker-with-a-user-script/)

With that question in mind, I want to explore the possibility (in context of a user-script) of modifying the Shared Worker constructor so that the mechanism responsible for loading the web worker is replaced with the GM function [`GM_xmlhttpRequest`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest), which works like [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) while ignoring same origin policies.

To be clear, I'm writing a user script for Stack Overflow to help automate a certain process for myself and others, and I need to communicate between two open SO tabs, which can be done nicely with a Shared Web Worker, however if you'll look at the related question I cited, there are problems with that.

Can the mechanism that loads the worker in Shared Web Workers be modified? Does it use the page's native `XMLHttpRequest` or is it some internal function which we can't touch? If it can be modified, how can I access it in order to perform the modification?

Comment: You can also use `storage` event to communicate between tabs. Have not tried user-script, though should be possible using  `.createObjectURL()` if at same origin?

Comment: @guest271314 Oh! My "Plan B" did involve using local or session storage to communicate but I was going to do something shameful to accomplish it: Check for a variable changes at a constant interval :( Thanks, that's much better!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034647/javascript-session-storage-variable-on-another-page , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343802/how-to-pass-data-from-one-html-page-to-second-in-php/ . May also be possible to use `filesystem:` if tabs both at same origin

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using `SharedWorker`?

Comment: @guest271314 just to pass messages between pages from the same domain without having to set a constant interval to check if a local storage variable had changed. I didn't realize the `storage` event reached all tabs for the domain. Much simpler alternative considering the difficulty of using a shared worker in a user-script. However I imagine someone might need to use a shared worker in a user-script, so this question is probably still useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> What are you trying to achieve using `SharedWorker`?
>
> to pass messages between pages from the same domain without having to
>   set a constant interval to check if a local storage variable had
>   changed.

You can use `storage` event to communicate messages between tabs at same origin

At `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="b.html" target="_blank">open b.html</a>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button>click</button>
    <script>
      var messages = [];
      var button = document.querySelector("button");
      var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
      window.addEventListener("storage", function(e) {
        console.log(e.newValue, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("messages")));

      });
      button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        messages.push(textarea.value);
        localStorage.setItem("messages", JSON.stringify(messages));
        localStorage.setItem("message", textarea.value);
        textarea.value = "";
      })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

b.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button>click</button>

    <script>
    var messages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("messages"));
      window.addEventListener("storage", function(e) {
        console.log(e.newValue, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("messages")));
      });
      var button = document.querySelector("button");
      var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
      button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        messages.push(textarea.value);
        localStorage.setItem("message", textarea.value);
        localStorage.setItem("messages", JSON.stringify(messages));
        textarea.value = "";
      })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/4nR7Rpu4zXSgTR831vQW?p=preview