# how to call one file input id into another file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

im having 2 html files, in my first file i have declared a variable and i want to use the same variable in my second file...

my first file code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function topics(clicked_id)
{
    var ids = clicked_id;
    var myObject, fol;
    myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    if(!myObject.FolderExists("D:/JavaScript/Work/Days/"+ids))
    {
        fol = myObject.CreateFolder("D:/JavaScript/Work/Days/"+ids);
    }
    load_page();
}

function load_page()
{
     open("file:///D:/JavaScript/Work/Topics_Page.html");
}
</script>
```

i want to use "ids" variable in my second file...
Thanks;

Comment: Are you trying to pass `ids` to an entirely different HTML `document`?

Comment: yeah, i wnat to use the ids in other html document...

Comment: There are several approaches which can be used to communicate between browsing contexts, several of which are described at Answers at linked Question at Answer

Comment: i didn't find any working procedure for me... help me out...

Comment: _"i didn't find any working procedure for me"_ Each of the procedures at Answer provide an approach to pass variables between different browsing contexts. Have you tried the approaches at each of the links at Answer?

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML documents have the same origin you can use `postMessage`, `MessageChannel`, `SharedWorker` or `storage` event to communicate between different browsing contexts, see

- [How can I load a shared web worker with a user-script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810002/)
- [Can we refer to JavaScript variables across webpages in a browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146595/)
- [how to pass data from one html page to second in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343802/)

You can use `localStorage` and `storage` event to use the same object variable, or define a local variable set to the value of `localStorage` at a different HTML `document`a having the same domain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>index</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="otherPage.html" target="_blank">otherPage.html</a>
  <h1>set id</h1>
  <script>
    let id;
    let h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
    h1.onclick = e => {
      id = `${Math.E * Math.PI * Math.random()}`;
      localStorage.setItem("id", id);
      console.log(`id: ${id} at ${e.type}`);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>other page</title>
  <script>
    let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
    console.log(`id: ${id} at ${document.title}`);
    onstorage = e => {
      console.log(`id: ${localStorage.getItem("id")} at ${e.type}`);
      id = localStorage.getItem("id");
      console.log(id);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>otherPage.html</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/m4RIdwgIl74Dk6YmGAgI?p=preview

Comment: my posted code is working absolutely perfect, my only point is to use the "ids" variable along with its value in the other html file... Thanks...

Comment: @Deepu _"it is just showing the "other page", specified in the otherpage document"_ Not sure what you mean?

Comment: in my first document code i have "ids" variable, i want to get the value of "ids" in another html document...