# Shouldn't this work? $.getScript("alert.js");

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is extremely simple,

In a `HTML` file, inside of a `<script>` tag, I have

```
$.getScript("alert.js");
```

**It doesn't work.** `alert.js` being a basic `alert()`. What am I missing? The error codes read,

`[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (alert.js, line 0)`

and

`[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Volumes/SSD2/kaely/kaely/alert.js?_=1471148162284. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I'm confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996001/jquery-load-only-working-in-firefox/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer in this post [Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Your browser (I'm guessing Chrome?) is not allowing this to occur. You could either try testing this in another browser or setting up a local web server.

Comment: Thanks. I'm running Safari so I assume this is a `webkit` issue. I don't understand how to add the feature and if it works when hosted as a public website.

Comment: You cannot load Ajax when running a website from a file, you have to be running a server

Comment: @JuanMendes Oh, thanks. Isn't that annoying for local development?

Comment: Ajax works with local development. It just doesn't work when accessing an html page as a file with the "file://" protocol

Comment: Thanks @kcdragon. Without `file://` how else does one view a local webpage?