# Javascript: Reading local text file from specific path without XMLHttpRequest and without input-type-file

Tags: javascript

Javascript: I want to read the content of a text file on my desk but without using XMLHttpRequest or input-type-file. I just want to give the path of the file as input to the javascript function. Any help please ?

Comment: Why do not use them??

Comment: I don't want to use XMLHttpRequest  because then I need to connect to the server. And I want the reading process to be automatic without the user interaction from the html file.

Comment: That would be a security problem

Comment: You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` without connecting to a server. _"And I want the reading process to be automatic without the user interaction"_ Are you trying to read files at user filesystem? Without user being aware that their filesystem is being read?

Comment: i tried to use XMLHttpRequest but it gives me error: javascripttt.js:16 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Fadwa/Desktop/testTxt.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: imagine going to any site they can read a file off your computer.... yikes

Comment: @FadwaEstuka _"i tried to use XMLHttpRequest but it gives me error"_ Are you trying at chrome browser? See [Jquery load  only working in firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32996001/2801559)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code snippet to do such a thing. I am afraid that you need to file selector due to the sandbox.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example reading a file</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      console.log(reader.result);
    };

    reader.readAsText(this.files[0]);
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#file').change(handleFileSelect);
  });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="file" id="file" name="files" />

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, reading local files in JavaScript without using the File API or an XMLHttpRequest (XHR) request is not possible. This is due to security concerns; allowing JavaScript to access local files on a user's device may result in security vulnerabilities.

XMLHttpRequest request means `.get()`, `.fetch()`, `xhr()`

To read remote file you need xhr request, and to read local files e.g `example.text` you are required `input type="file"`, and write JS code for it and user will manually choose that file and `new FileReader()` method to read file content.

**Summarize**:
If you want to add hard-coded file path, and want JavaScript to read that file content, But unfortunately it is not possible.