# Reading RGB bytes from a local image

Tags: javascript

I have an image stored as a png (I could convert it to bmp too). I want to open it in JavaScript and get the raw RGB bytes. It is enough if this works locally in Chrome. So I open `./index.html` in the browser which loads an image in the same directory, e.g. with `<img src=myimage.png>`. However, I need the proper original data, without any compression or artifacts. I can't use NodeJS.

I saw a similar question, [Get image data in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript), but it requires that the image is hosted somewhere. I'm also not sure how to get the raw RGB bytes, the results I got from trying those examples looked like they were still encoded as png.

EDIT: As one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42916772/770335) to the other SO question mentions, a canvas will re-encode the data and reading from it won't give me exactly the same values as in the original.

Comment: put it on a canvas then - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373851/reading-the-rgb-value-of-a-canvas-pixel

Comment: The other SO question I mentioned says that this wouldn't give me the original data, but slightly modified re-encoded data.

Comment: " it requires that the image is hosted somewhere."  Didn't you say image is hosted somewhere, in the same directory as your index.html?

Comment: @JeffUK, the XHR request doesn't work with something like `<img src=myimage.png>`, it requires HTTP. I could start a web server on localhost, but I would prefer to avoid that.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606016/javascript-reading-local-text-file-from-specific-path-without-xmlhttprequest-an  if it was a BMP you could read it in as a string and parse it yourself?

Comment: I would prefer if I didn't have to use a library to do this. And is manually parsing the BMP seriously the only option for something this simple?