# Not able to access webcam (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am learning to use getUserMedia() to access webcam in javascript. But i am getting an error -
`Not allowed to load local resource: blob:null/3485f5b8-46c1-4a40-946a-8de2588720f0`

I searched on the net but they said that i needed an https connection or something, file urls are not allowed, but i didn't completely understand what is going on.

the code is -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="stuff, to, help, search, engines, not" name="keywords">
<meta content="What this page is about." name="description">
<meta content="Display Webcam Stream" name="title">
<title>Display Webcam Stream</title>
  
<style>
#container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    border: 10px #333 solid;
}
#videoElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    background-color: #666;
}
</style>
</head>
  
<body>
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">
     
    </video>
</div>
<script>
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
 
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;
 
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
}
 
function handleVideo(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}
 
function videoError(e) {
    // do something
 console.log("error");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Prompts to allow webcam here, at `file:` protocol and stacksnippets at firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For privacy and security reasons, Google decided to allow certain features only to "secure" origins, i.e. `getUserMedia` is only available on websites using HTTPS.

For more of the reasoning you can read [their article on this](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features).

Your code is fine and works fine when used via HTTPS, the easiest way to do that during development is probably [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/cuheqojahu/edit?html,output).

Comment: But isnt the file scheme included in list of secure origins?

Comment: Yes, and in fact it works from the local file system as well as http://localhost for me - but that may depend on your operating system and what not, so the safe bet is HTTPS.

Comment: How to work fine in android chrome browser? I test the jsbin link. It shows "error" in the console.

Comment: The Code on JSBin is over a year old and uses outdated APIs - see MDN for the recent APIs to use instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying at chromium, chrome at `file:` protocol, close all chromium, chrome instances, then re-launch chromium, chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag to allow browser access to files at local filesystem. See also [Jquery load() only working in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996001/jquery-load-only-working-in-firefox/)

Comment: Why are these changes not recommended?

Comment: @DhruvChadha For security reasons. The flag does not have to be set permanently. You can create different launchers for using different flags and without any flags set. You can also launch chrome or chromium from `terminal` `$ google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files` or `$ chromium-browser --allow-file-access-from-files`, where when instance is closed at `terminal` or at browser the flag will not be permanently set at desktop or other launcher