# Finance data from alphavantage using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, quotes

I am using jQuery to call the AlphaVantage finance API for stock quotes in an HTML file on the local machine.  However, the .get or .ajax calls are failing.  I have tried using crossdomain and jsonp, but still the call fails in the error handler.  The error text in the error handler is blank - so no indication is provided why it is failing.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo', 
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("Post error: " + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: See [Jquery load() only working in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996001/jquery-load-only-working-in-firefox/), [Read local XML with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279589/read-local-xml-with-js/)

Comment: Just remove ; at the end of the URL

Comment: That was a copy/paste error on my part when I was writing the question - removed the semi-colon, but that does not fix the problem - still get a blank error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo (the ';' after the url). Remove it and try again...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo'**;**, 
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("Post error: " + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: That was a copy/paste error on my part when I was writing the question - removed the semi-colon, but that does not fix the problem - still get a blank error.

Comment: I've realized you say that your using a local file (your code works perfectly in fiddle)! Looks like the browser security protection (doesn't allow that ajax calls by default if you're using a local file). Check the links @guest271314 has provided you