# JS: how can I base64 encode a local file without XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to base64 encode a local file. It's next to my `.js` file so there's no uploading going on. Solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833797/convert-local-image-to-base64-string-in-javascript#32833857) (using `XMLHttpRequest`) get a cross-site scripting error.

I'm trying something like this (which doesn't work but it might help explain my problem):

```
var file = 'file.jpg'
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
   var res = e.target.result;
   console.log(res);
};
var f = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Anyone have any experience doing this locally?

Comment: so you want to base64 encode the file on the disk?

Comment: Is this using nodejs or in browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833797/convert-local-image-to-base64-string-in-javascript#32833857) (using XMLHttpRequest) get a cross-site
> scripting error.

If using chrome or chromium browser, you could launch with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag set to allow request of resource from local filesystem using `XMLHttpRequest()` or `canvas.toDataURL()`.

You can use `<img>` element, `<canvas>` element `.toDataURL()` to create `data URL` of local image file without using `XMLHttpRequest()`

```
var file = "file.jpg";
var img = new Image;
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
img.onload = function() {
  canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  var res = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1); // set image `type` to `image/jpeg`
  console.log(res);
}
img.src = file;
```

You could alternatively use `XMLHttpRequest()` as described at [Convert local image to base64 string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833797/convert-local-image-to-base64-string-in-javascript#32833857).

See also [How to print all the txt files inside a folder using java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634049/how-to-print-all-the-txt-files-inside-a-folder-using-java-script) .

---

For a details of difference of returned `data URI` from either approach see [canvas2d toDataURL() different output on different browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273990/canvas2d-todataurl-different-output-on-different-browser/36274211#36274211)

As described by @Kaiido at [comment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32235238#32235238) below

> it will first decode it, at this stage it's still your file, then it
> will paint it to the canvas (now it's just raw pixels) and finally it
> will reencode it (it has nothing to do with your original file
> anymore) check the dataURI strings... They're compeltely different and
> even if you do the canvas operation from two different browsers,
> you'll have different outputs, while `FileReader` will always give you
> the same output, since it encode the file directly, it doesn't decode
> it.

Comment: Actually I think that the flag is also needed for canvas workaround, browsers that do prevent `file://` xhr will taint the canvas if an image from this protocol has been drawn on it. Also, remember that this workaround won't give an exact representation of the file, it will be first decoded to raw bitmap, then re-encoded to whatever you set as parameter of `toDataURL()`. Oh and you always forget to set the canvas width and height in your recent examples, it would be a good habit to include them IMO.

Comment: @Kaiido Included setting of `type` at `.toDataURL()`. Missed that portion at Question and initial Answer. _"And It won't even work as a workaround to the actual problem without setting the flag, this should be made clear too."_ Believe this is presently clear to OP, as error was returned without flag being set?

Comment: @Kaiido Updated to `image/jpg`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120657/discussion-between-kaiido-and-guest271314).