# How to send emails with Local Attachments using Gmail API and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, base64, gmail-api, mime-types, email-attachments

I'm building a Chrome extension that works with Gmail API and i need to send emails with local files (using their local file path) as attachments.
I saw that with Gmail API, attachments need to be base64 encoded and then you can send them as a POST request. So i tried this:

```
// Here i convert the file to base64
const fileToBase64 = (filename, filepath) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var file = new File([filename], filepath);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    // Read file content on file loaded event
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      resolve(event.target.result);
    };

    // Convert data to base64 
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
};

//Here i trigger the event, get the auth token and create the mail
    $('#test').on('click', function(){
      chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
        console.log(token);
        fileToBase64("pic4.jpg", "C:\Users\Davide\Downloads\pic4.jpg").then(result => {
          console.log(result);

          var splittedResult = result.split('base64,')[1];
          var mail = [
            'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="foo_bar_baz"\r\n',
            'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
            'From: address1@gmail.com\r\n',
            'To: address2@gmail.com\r\n',
            'Subject: Subject Text\r\n\r\n',

            '--foo_bar_baz\r\n',
            'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n',
            'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n',

            'The actual message text goes here\r\n\r\n',

            '--foo_bar_baz\r\n',
            'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n',
            'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n',
            'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pic4.jpg"\r\n\r\n',

            //base64 splitted result of previous function
            splittedResult, '\r\n\r\n',

            '--foo_bar_baz--'
          ].join('');

          // Here i send the mail
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart",
            contentType: "message/rfc822",
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+ token );
            },
            data: mail
          }); 

        });
```

Result: i receive a mail at the destination address ( i receive also a copy to the source address, idk why) but the mail contains an empty attachment with the filename i've chosen (pic4.jpg) (cannot open it).

[Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NsN8.png)

It seems the error to be in the base64 encoding from the absolute path, is there a way to fix or another way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784167/gmail-api-for-sending-email-with-attachment

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane Tried to split the base64 url but it's not working, same result..

Comment: This is the information provided in the FileReader documentation:                                                                                                                                                     
  The blob's result cannot be directly decoded as Base64 without first removing the Data-URL declaration preceding the Base64-encoded data. To retrieve only the Base64 encoded string, first remove data:*/*;base64, from the result.                                                                              
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: @ziganotschka Already tried, splitted the string from "base64, " and nothing changed.. Tried also to add a relative path to the image but it's not working.

Comment: The main difference I see between your code and the answer Diodeus mentioned in his comment is that you use the method readAsDataURL(). Don't know if you can locate your file in such a way that you can use the method toDataURL() instead - as in the other case, to see if it works.

Comment: @ziganotschka i'm pretty sure the error is not there: toDataURL() is a specific Canvas function and works only with images; readAsDataURL() works with every file you place in. I Think the error is in the File constructor, i don't know if i can enter the absolute path this way i do.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking - maybe if you upload the file somewhere (for a test) and try to retrieve it by URL- you can see if this is what causes you the error.

Comment: @ziganotschka Yup, the error is there: i've made an Input file form with HTML and everything works. I should now find a way to create the File from a local path without using the input form (probably not possible for security reasons) or another way to upload the entire attachment.

Answer (score 0):

### You can open a file from a local path with XMLHttpRequest().open() in order to pass it to reader.readAsDataURL().

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32833857/11599789) example.