# Convert local img to base64 with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, base64url

I am in React hooks trying to utilise code in this question  [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833797/convert-local-image-to-base64-string-in-javascript)- but, as I think someone is pointing out, there are problems implementing this in a local environment.

I have a variable containing my src path:

```
import avatar from '../../Assets/Photos/avatar.png'
```

Then I try to set the photo as a useState state:

```
 const [ photo, setPhoto ] = useState(avatar)
```

Then I use useEffect to wait until the variable has loaded:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (photo) {
        console.log("PHOTO EXISTS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", photo)
        console.log(convertImgToBase64())

    }
}, [photo])
```

And the convertImgToBase64 function is almost identical to the one in the question I referenced:

```
    function convertImgToBase64()
{
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    let img = document.createElement('avatar');
    img.src = photo;
    img.onload = function()
    {
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        canvas = null;
        return dataURL
    };
}
```

This returns undefined - why is this please?

Comment: Try setting `img.src` after `img.onload`

Comment: Ok that seems to work! I have no idea why tho - surely an image needs a src before it loads??

Comment: It seems that order matters in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Create an image state:

```
const[image, setImage] = useState("")
```

Function to convert to base64:

```
const convertBase64 = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

      fileReader.onload = () => {
        resolve(fileReader.result);
      };

      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });
};
```

Set your image state to base64 string image:

```
const handleFileRead = async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const base64 = await convertBase64(file);
    setImage(base64);
};

<input type="file"  multiple accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" onChange={(e) => handleFileRead(e)} />
```